Rmarkdown finds image when run but not when "knit"
I'm trying to include a figure in an RMD pdf with this code:
knitr::include_graphics(paste0(here::here(), '/figures/species/', cur_yr,'/place_fig1_', cur_yr, '.png'), dpi = 125). 

This figure definitely exists in this location, and it runs successfully within the code chunk when I press the run button, and a figure appears. However, when I press knit to turn the whole thing into a pdf, I get this error:

Error in `knitr::include_graphics()`:
! Cannot find the file(s): "../../figures/species/2023/place_fig1_2023.png"
Backtrace:
 1. knitr::include_graphics(...)
Execution halted


I tried specifically setting the working directory for the rmd but it did not work. I suspect it may have something to do with a different working directory when I press the run button vs when I press the knit button, but I do not know for sure.
I currently use R version 4.4.0 and RStudio. It successfully runs on another machine with R version 4.3.3.
I tried listing out the full directory location of the image instead of using here() and got the same error. I also tried setting the working directory in the first chunk with knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "directory location") to no avail.

What happens if you try hard coding the complete path rather than using the relative path (e.g. ../../)?
